# Packages not working when using Python in Rmarkdown

Tags: python, r, pandas, r-markdown, reticulate

I am using RMarkdown to make a beamer presentation using both R and Python code/analysis. I am using the `reticulate` package to do so, but certain packages are not found when I render the presentation with knitr. For instance, pandas works, but seaborn does not. Here is a reprex:

```
---
title: "R Python Presentation"
author: "Name"
date: "11/16/2020"
output:
  beamer_presentation: default
  ioslides_presentation: default
---
```

```
R code chunk:

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = T)

library(reticulate)
```

#### This works:

```
# Python code chunk:

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"State": ["AL", "AK", "NJ", "MA", "WA"],
"Pop": [34, 56, 43, 45, 22]})
```

```
print(df.head())
```

#### This does not work:

```
# Python code chunk:

import seaborn

seaborn.barplot(x = "State", y = "Pop", data= df)
```

Comment: What error do you get? Are you use `seaborn` is installed on the computer?

Comment: Yes, I use `seaborn` in Python (for which I use Anaconda/Spyder). Error I get: `Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : ModuleNotFoundError: No module names 'seaborn' Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> import -> py_module_import Execution halted`